# Why static casting Derived to Base with private inheritance causes a conversion between "const Derived" to "const Base"?

Tags: c++, downcast

```
class Base {
};
class Derived: private Base {
};
int main() {
    Derived d;
    static_cast<Base>(d);
}
```

I understand that such a cast is an error because of private inheritance. However, what I am interested in is why the error message is:

```
error: cannot cast 'const Derived' to its private base class 'const Base'
```

In particular, why is it not casting 'Derived' to 'Base'? Why is there a const here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `static_cast<Base&>(d)` might be what you wanted to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_cast<Base>(d)` calls the implicit copy constructor `Base(const Base&)` with the argument `Derived d`, that is passed by a reference `const Derived&` and can't be further converted to `const Base&` by the well known reason to you.